# Generating clean formatted json with Laravel pivot tables

Tags: json, laravel, eloquent

So I'm running tables with localization but I keep the strings in a separate "master" table.

Say I have a table for each entity:

```
Products
  id
  price
  ...
```

a translation table

```
Translations
  id
  name
  description
  ...
```

a relationship table

```
product_translation
  product_id
  translation_id
  lang --enum('en', 'es', 'fr',...)
```

**Problem: the not so pretty json that comes with this**

So I've created a `BaseModel` which uses a many to many relationship:

```
public function translations()
{
  return $this
  ->belongsToMany('Translation')
  ->where('lang', '=' App::getLocale());
}
```

So with that I can do `Product::with('translations')->get()` for my json. However...

**What I wanted**

```
{
    "name": "Foo",
    "description": "Bar",
    "price": "1000",
    "stock": "10",
}
```

**What I got**

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "price": "1000",
  "stock": "10",
  "translations": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Foo",
      "description": "Bar",
      "pivot": {
        "product_id": "1",
        "translation_id": "1"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see there's just too much baggage with the output. How do I restrict which fields I want to produce my desired json output?

EDIT: Discovered https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/745

So using `$hidden` I am able to hide specific fields. Neat.

EDIT: Using `$appends` with a `getNameAttribute()` accessor method I'm able to create a new property to my json. Problem solved!

Comment: Would be nice if you could post your answer and mark this as solved? Have you used this: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators?

Answer (score 2):

That is the code that should be added to the class Product (As answered in the question itself):

```
class Product {

    protected $hidden = ['id', 'translations'];

    protected $appends = ['name', 'description'];

    public function getNameAttribute()
    {
        return $this->translations->name;
    }

    public function getDescriptionAttribute()
    {
        return $this->translations->description;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can play with Laravel queries to obtain only the attributes you need.
See in documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#selects

What about addind ->select() to recieve only what you really need.